# how to set domain for angularJS $cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

It seems [$cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies) only allows to set the Key/Value pair.

But i need to set the domain parameter as well. I need to set the cookie from one subdomain of website and use it from all subdomains of website.

I am using the angularJS and Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 8):

Currently this is not implemented in angular (1.2.7). You may have a look at angular.js line 4348 - the relevant code a little bit reduced:

```
if (value === undefined) {
   // Delete the cookie
   rawDocument.cookie = escape(name) + 
          "=;path=" + cookiePath + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
} else {
   // set or update the cookie value
   rawDocument.cookie = escape(name) + '=' + escape(value) + ';path=' + cookiePath);
}
```

as you can see the ;domain=XYZ is not included. You have to write your own cookiestore that implements this feature - but this should be very easy.

Comment: Update: AngularJS 1.4.0-beta.6 [adds this feature](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features).

Answer (score 4):

I've created module for AngularJS to solve this issue:

https://github.com/stevermeister/ng-biscuit

now you can simply set options:

```
cookieStore.put('x', 5, {domain: 'youdomain.com'})
```

Comment: what is minimum AngularJS version supported?

Comment: `cookieStore` is deprecated in later versions of Angular, I believe. It is in `1.4 +`, at least.

Comment: I've already put "ng-biscuit" like deprecated, because cookieStore was fixed - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/92c366d205da36ec26502aded23db71a6473dad7

Comment: $cookieStore.put() does not have third parameter