# Angular $cookieStore service - share cookie with sub domains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I was wondering if there is a way to access an cookie set using angular $cookieStore service, from several different subdomains, let's say: `api.yoursite.com` `www.yoursite.com` and jsut `yoursite.com`

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookieStore) doesn't mention this issue at all.

Is there a solution, or do I have to use the lower level JavaScript cookies API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `cookieStore` service in angular doesn't support this.

This feature has been requested before: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/950
and others have asked similar questions: [how to set domain for angularJS $cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477937/how-to-set-domain-for-angularjs-cookies)

It seems your options are to write your own cookeistore or use something else.

**I would recommend trying: https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie**

Comment: Just saw the date angular-cookie was updated. It's not being updated anymore. I'm aware that if it doesn't get updated, it doesn't mean it's bad. I also saw few questions on the Issues tab unanswered.