# sharing cookies across domain using ngCookies/$cookiestore

Tags: angularjs, cookiestore, angular-cookies

I want to use ngCookies so I can re-use the login cookies on another host under the same domain. This way, when I login on app1.example.com and I visit app2.example.com, I won't need to login anymore. It will use the cookies that was created in app1.example.com. Can someone please share a link that I can read up on.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654652/angular-cookiestore-service-share-cookie-with-sub-domains.

Comment: I got it working using ngBiscuit instead. Had to trick my o.s. as well by editing the hosts file as well as using a real http server than gulp serve